# Cannot zoom in to current location in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

```
public class Game_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private Location currentLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE =101;
    private FrameLayout map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        map=findViewById(R.id.map);

        fusedClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        getLocation();
    }
    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }

            Task<Location> task = fusedClient.getLastLocation();

            task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        currentLocation = location;
                        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                        assert supportMapFragment != null;
                        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(Game_Activity.this);
                    }
                }
            });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Player");
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLocation();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is my code I am trying to make a map on for it to zoom it to my current location when i start it (like in pokemon go) and it doesnt zoom in.I tried to debug and the location in the on success method seems to stay null anyone got any fix?

A fix for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be receiving a null current Location on success callback. Look on this [Location Callback documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/request-updates) to get the lastest location. You can use ViewModel to update the coordinate and then use that coordinate to zoom on the map.

Answer (score 0):

working code:

```
package il.co.jonathan.monstercatch.ACTIVITIES;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import il.co.jonathan.monstercatch.R;

public class Game_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private Location currentLocation;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE =101;
    private FrameLayout map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        map=findViewById(R.id.map);
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(@NonNull LocationResult locationResult) {
                if(locationResult == null){
                    return;
                }
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()){
                    if(location != null){
                        currentLocation = location;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        fusedClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        getLocation();
    }
    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }

            Task<Location> task = fusedClient.getLastLocation();

            task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        currentLocation = location;
                        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                        assert supportMapFragment != null;
                        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(Game_Activity.this);
                    }
                }
            });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Player");
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLocation();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ACTIVITIES.Game_Activity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```